# unable to run python script with Node-red

Tags: python, node-red

I am new in node-red, I just tried to do a simple test before doing a bigger project. So I created the basic python script with only `print "Hello world"` on it. Then I use the "exec" node and inside the command I wrote `python test.py` then I connected the output of the node to the "Debug" node and finally "Deploy" it. Nothing happen inside the debug messages...

Someone knows why ?

thank you

Comment: Where did you put the python script (`test.py`)?

Comment: in a folder inside my desktop

Comment: So what makes you think that Node-RED knows to look in that folder?

Comment: Also what do you have before the exec node? if there is no input, then nothing will trigger it.

Comment: so I replace 'python test.py' by 'python /home/user/Desktop/NodeRedTest/test.py' but it does not work

Comment: I have nothing in input since I do not know what to put.. sorry, I am starting with node-red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: You need to give the full path to the script you are trying to run.

Second problem with no input the `exec` node will never run. For the simple test you can add an `inject` node that will fire when you press the button on the left hand end of the node in the editor, or you can configure it to run once on startup/deploy or to fire at regular intervals.

I also suggest you read the Node-RED doc about creating your first [flow](https://nodered.org/docs/tutorials/first-flow)